# Pass view contextual filter arguments programmatically

Tags: 7, views

I want to pass contextual filter arguments programmatically to a view. I know it can be done through `views_get_view` and `views_embed_view`, but I want to pass it to a view's page display. Also I want to pass multiple arguments to the view, so it won't be good to pass all the arguments in the url. 
I tried to pass the arguments using `$view->args = implode('+', $args);` in `hook_views_pre_render`, but it didn't work.
Does anyone know how to pass contextual filter arguments using any of view hooks?

Comment: `I want to pass multiple arguments to the view, so it won't be good to pass all the arguments in the url` What kind of arguments do you want to pass? I ask because maybe you can archive it with the Views UI.

Comment: I want to pass multiple tids, I get those tids from custom solr search, so there might be a huge number of tids.

Comment: I don't think this can be done without either `views_embed_view` or url arguments. While you can write a 'default argument' plugin for views I am not sure how you would feed data to it if not over the url. If you don't want to really pass data but rather generate it somehow, you can use the UI with 'provide default value' and the 'php' option on the contextual filter itself which is the same. `hook_views_pre_render`doesn't work as the db was already queried.

Comment: Yes, you are partially right @Zuzuesque. It can't be done with `hook_views_pre_render`, but it can be done using `hook_views_pre_view()`. I got the solution and will update soon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the solution. It can be done using [hook_views_pre_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_view/7.x-3.x). Since `hook_views_pre_view()` allows altering a view at the very beginning of views processing, before anything is done, I am able to feed the arguments to the view.

```
function MODULE_NAME_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
  if ($view->name == 'myview' && $display_id == 'page_1') {
    $tids = custom_function();
    $args[] = implode('+', $tids);
  }
}
```

Hope this is useful to someone :)