# Drupal views filter with latest month with content

Tags: views

I am working to show a page that will display a current issue section, by which all the articles from the latest month whatever articles were posted are only shown.

Suppose the last posted set of article are December 2015 and after that nothing is posted, that view must show all articles posted on December, 2015. If the last posted set of articles were on January 2016, it must show list of articles posted on the month of January 2016 like that.

How it can be adjusted in views ?

Comment: Create a custom module. Get the created date of the latest article (I'll let you figure this part out), then use [Pass view contextual filter arguments programmatically](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207672/pass-view-contextual-filter-arguments-programmatically) to pass the month to views.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a date filter using the create date and set the granularity to month. The setting for the relative date field should be set to be equal to now.