# How to pass seperate contextual filter values to a view and get results programatically?

Tags: 7, views

I've a view having two (separate) contextual filters, say `node id` and `taxonomy id`. We can pass separate contextual filter values with a "`/`". example: 12,13,14/8,9 as URL arguments.

But how can we get the view results by passing the dynamic contextual filter values to the view?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass view contextual filter arguments programmatically](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207672/pass-view-contextual-filter-arguments-programmatically)

Comment: @AjitS My question is about passing separate contextual filter values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go.

```
 $nodes_str = implode(',', $nids); // $nids is an dynamic array.
 $args[] = $nodes_str; // First contextual filter argument. 12,13,14.. etc
 $args[] = $tag; // Second contextual filter arguments 8,9.. etc
 $view = views_get_view('view_machine_name');
 $view->set_display('display_name');
 $view->set_arguments($args);
 $view->pre_execute();
 $result = $view->execute();
 $output = $view->result;
```

If need futher details of the view parameters. You can debug the values using the [hook_views_pre_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_view/7.x-3.x)

```
function YOUR_MODULE_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {

}
```

Hope this helps someone.